# How to extract coordinates of a geometric object without array in Shapely

Tags: python, arrays, shapely

How to extract only the value from an array without the text "array" and "typecode"?

Array is `shapely.linestring.centroid.xy`:

```
a = LineString.centroid.xy
print(a)
>> (array('d', [-1.72937...45182697]), array('d', [2.144161...64685937]))
print(a[0])
>> array('d', [-1.7293720645182697])
```

I need only the `-1.7293...` as a float not the whole *array* business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, individual coordinates of the [`Point`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Point) can be accessed by `x` and `y` properties. And since [`object.centroid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.centroid) returns a `Point`, you can simply do:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import LineString
>>> line = LineString([(0, 0), (2, 1)])
>>> line.centroid.x
1.0
>>> line.centroid.y
0.5
```

Additionaly, geometric objects such as `Point`, `LinearRing` and `LineString` have a [`coords`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#coordinate-sequences) attribute that returns a special `CoordinateSequence` object from which you can get individual coordinates:

```
>>> line.coords
<shapely.coords.CoordinateSequence at 0x7f60e1556390>
>>> list(line.coords)
[(0.0, 0.0), (2.0, 1.0)]
>>> line.centroid.coords[0]
(1.0, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(a[0][0])
```

you are working with array inside array.

[image]

```
import array
a=(array.array('d',[-2.2,3,2,2]),array('d',[2,3,4]))
print(a[0][0])
```

Comment: You're right, my bad. Taken my answer down + upvoted to you.

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of screenshots. [Explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: yeah but he want just one line.